# no prebuilt wasm-opt binaries

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I'm trying to build some webassembly rust applications on my raspberry pi (3b). Everything is going well, although I'm getting an error when running `wasm-pack`

```
~/rust/wasm-game-of-life $ wasm-pack build
[INFO]: Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]: Compiling to Wasm...
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.50s
[INFO]: Installing wasm-bindgen...
Error: no prebuilt wasm-opt binaries are available for this platform: Unrecognized target!
To disable `wasm-opt`, add `wasm-opt = false` to your package metadata in your `Cargo.toml`.
```

It seems no `wasm-opt` binaries are found for my (armv71) platform. But it seems easy enough to clone them from [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) and build them myself.

But my question is how to add them to webassembly, so that they are found?

edit: to be clear, the build completes 'successfully', i.e. I can run the package. However, I want to use the size or speed optimizations of `wasm-opt`

Comment: You can disable the automatic call to `wasm-opt` by adding `wasm-opt = false` to  `[package.metadata.wasm-pack.profile.release]` (or `.dev`) in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: @user2722968 yeah, I can read that... but I actually want `wasm-opt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afaid there's no solution for this yet, as it's simply not implemented in the code (but it seems to be on the TODO list: there's [comments in the code](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/blob/d46d1c69b788956160deed5e4e603f4f2780ffcf/src/wasm_opt.rs#L50), but no actual matching implementation).

I've opened an [issue on the github](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/913), which is still open. If you have the same issue, please report it in that issue, so it will get more priority.

There's a fix suggested by [this issue report](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/pull/957)(specifically [this commit](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/pull/957/commits/f66d321ba9bf08d327bccc3e2f2945c0c3b53f69)) but it yet needs to be reviewed, tested and merged

**update** the PR has been merged, so it should be fixed now. I don't know as I don't have time for Rust at this point in my life